# Eclipse PDT / XDebug - How to move instruction pointer backward?

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I have setup eclipse PDT and Xdebug. During debugging, I want to move instruction pointer backwards one or more steps. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently not possible. But the Xdebug author (me) is working on something like this. It is in a very early state though! The git branch is at https://github.com/derickr/triceratops

Comment: Is this possible now?